# Разбиение строки с разделителем на столбцы

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, split

### Таблица БД

У таблицы есть колонка `TestResult`, в которой хранится результаты участников (в %) по некоторым показателям:

```
DECLARE @TestResults TABLE(ParticipCode INT, Elements VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TestResults VALUES (1, '0,50;0,20;0,30')
INSERT INTO @TestResults VALUES (2, '0,60;0,24;0,32')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### НЕОБХОДИМО

Необходимо получить среднее значение по каждому показателю, т.е.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И нет разницы в каком виде они будут представлены в результирующем наборе -

по строкам

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или столбцам

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить такое? После того как получится составить скрипт, я хочу на его основе сделать хранимую процедуру, которая принимала бы такой массив и вычисляла средние.

---

### Попытки

**1.** Работаю в `SQL Server 2016` и естественно я решил прибегнуть к новшеству `STRING_SPLIT`. Но к сожалению моих знаний и попыток хватило только на умение распарсить одну строку:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT TOP 1 Elements FROM @TestResults);
SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@str, ';')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**2.** Также на форуме нашел [решение](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d341a/25), которое основано на встроенной функции `PARSENAME`. Оно не подходит, т.к. эта функция перестанет работать с более чем 4 показателей. *У меня в примере 3, но в реальности их больше.*

Comment: Надо понимать, что "измените структуру так, чтобы нормализовать данные" - не предлагать?

Comment: Не сможет он STRING_SPLIT использовать, потому как у него показатели позиционные, а при разделении эта позиционность благополучно потеряется...

Comment: @Akina , да - я знаю что она у меня денормализована. Необходимо решить задачу именно с такими входными параметрами.

Comment: @Akina Так надо же получить среднее, думаю порядок не важен

Comment: @Mike как раз ему порядок важен: "Необходимо получить среднее значение по **каждому** показателю". Если часть взять из первого значения. часть из второго, то получится средняя температура по больнице.

Comment: @Mike Хотя подумал я... да, позиционность он потеряет, но ведь после разделения можно посчитать `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParticipCode ORDER BY INSTR(OneElement, Elements))`, который собственно и будет позицией в списке. И по этому выражению вполне можно группировать.

Comment: @Akina Зато это гарантированно собьет его с толку при повторяющихся элементах. Гарантированное решение одно - в рекурсивном CTE отрезать от начала строки по одному элементу параллельно их нумеруя и отдавая на следующий уровень рекурсии укороченную на первый элемент строку. Но с скудным набором строковых функций ms sql мне это лень писать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня под рукой, к сожалению, нет SQL Server 2016, чтобы проверить свой скрипт, попробую предложить вариант, если где-то ошибся - поправьте меня.

```
select t.rn, avg(t.value)
from (
      select tr.ParticipCode
           , row_number() over (partition by tr.ParticipCode order by tr.ParticipCode) as rn
           , cast(ss.value as float) as value
      from @TestResults tr
           cross apply STRING_SPLIT(tr.Elements, ';') as ss
     ) as t
group by t.rn
```

Comment: Работать что то подобное думаю может, но за корректный результат во всех случаях я бы не поручился. никто не сказал, что row_number пронумерует значения в правильном порядке

Comment: @Mike, порядок действительно не гарантирован, но должен все же выдерживаться - все таки это функция, а не скан физических страниц, при котором сервер может оптимизировать возвращаемый набор в зависимости от физического места хранения данных. В любом случае, можно заменить функцию string_split на самописную, где набор будет нумероваться - такие функции активно использовались, когда еще не было реализации от Microsoft.

Comment: Код не работает - _Тип данных операнда varchar недопустим для оператора avg_. Попробовал подправить: `avg(convert(float, value))` и все равно не работает: _Столбец "t.rn" недопустим в списке выбора, поскольку он не содержится ни в агрегатной  функции, ни в предложении GROUP BY._

Comment: @adamshakhabov, в конце добавьте group by rn. В ответе сейчас поправлю.

Comment: В продолжение обсуждения добавлю интересную статью про исследование производительности этой функции - исходя из выводов статьи, производительность значимо превосходит имевшиеся ранее варианты разделения строк. И в одном из будущих релизов планируется добавить возврат точного положения элемента в наборе. Адрес статьи: https://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-server-2016/string-split